# Navigator.push and pressing backbutton show previous screen for a moment before loading main screen

Tags: flutter, navigator

```dart
if(topics.title==AppLocalizations.of(context)!.basicAlgebra){

          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MathScreen(teXViewWidget: MathFormulas.basicAlgebra(context),title:AppLocalizations.of(context)!.mathematics)));
        }
```

[image: Back button pressed show two screen]

```
class _MathScreenState extends State<MathScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final bottomContentText = Stack(
      children: [
        TeXView(
          renderingEngine: const TeXViewRenderingEngine.katex(),
          child: TeXViewColumn(

            children: [
              widget.teXViewWidget,
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );

    final topContent = Expanded(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: bottomContentText,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Please share more content and modify your question.

Comment: Can you look into it now?